# Using Azure RM Powershell how do I find out which Recovery Services Vault VM is connected to?

Tags: powershell, azure, backup

I can clearly see they can do that in the Portal, so must be the way - without looping through all available recovery services vaults - to get the RSV VM belongs to.

In other words: I know only VM - Name, Id etc. I want to know the Vault it belongs to. 
Without traversing through all the vaults in the subscription - I know how to achieve this, but it's too slow with many Vaults.

Traversing / Looping / FOREACHing through all vaults trying to find the VM is not an acceptable, although working, solution.

Comment: well, the straight forward way is to loop through your vaults and check what they have protected, this is probably the only way to go unless there is some property on a VM that indicates its being protected by some vault, did you examine VM properties?

Comment: Yes, I agree, based on my knowledge, one VM does not have property about protected by vaults.

Comment: I'm kind of refusing to believe that Microsoft portal developers loop through Vaults to find out the VM. They must have something :)

Comment: can you paste the protected vm properties into the question?

Comment: I can't really - there's too much info that will need to be obfuscated, but if you have such a VM, you can easily run in Powershell `Get-AzureRmVM | ? Name -EQ 'VMNAME' | ConvertTo-Json` and get all the info. Deep inside there's base64 encoded json - but it doesn't have Vault in it.

Comment: well i don't have protected vm

Comment: `get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName *** -Name *** -DisplayHint Expand`. list all information. There is none about vault in it.